# Get the dates of last five answers by top users

Tags: support, data-explorer

I've been trying to get the dates of the last five answers by the top 50 users (say `Reputation > 3000 AND Count(Posts.Id) > 50`). I've modeled my SEDE query after [another popular query](https://data.stackexchange.com/chemistry/query/952/top-500-answerers-on-the-site) and here's what I have achieved:

```
SELECT TOP ##UserCount##
  Users.Id as [User Link]
  [Answer 1] as [???]
  [Answer 2] as [???]
  [Answer 3] as [???]
  [Answer 4] as [???]
  [Answer 5] as [???]
FROM 
  Posts
  INNER JOIN
   Users ON Users.Id = OwnerUserId
WHERE Users.Reputation > ##MinReputation## AND PostTypeId = 2
HAVING Count(Posts.Id) > ##MinPostsCount##
ORDER BY 
  Users.Reputation DESC
```

What do I fill in those `[???]` to get the `CreationDate` of the last 5 answers? ("last" defined by `CreationDate` not `LastActivityDate`) I was also hoping if those five answer texts would be linked to the original post.

I have mainly been reading stuff from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede), and couldn't find information for my request there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Glorfindel already did the heavy lifting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/308056/158100) by fixing the base query that generates the correct data all I had to add was the  5 column [pivot query](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15).

Here is [that query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1359146?UserCount=10&MinReputation=100000&MinPostsCount=10):

```
;with ranked_posts as
(
SELECT OwnerUserId
     , Id
     -- , creationdate
     , RANK() OVER (Partition BY OwnerUserId
                    ORDER BY CreationDate DESC) AS Rank
FROM Posts
WHERE PostTypeId = 2
  AND OwnerUserId IN (  
  SELECT TOP ##UserCount##
    Users.Id
  FROM Posts
  INNER JOIN Users ON Users.Id = OwnerUserId
  WHERE Users.Reputation > ##MinReputation##
  AND PostTypeId = 2
  GROUP BY Users.Id, Users.Reputation
  HAVING Count(Posts.Id) > ##MinPostsCount##
  ORDER BY  Users.Reputation DESC 
  )  
),
answers as (
select posts.id, concat(
  format(posts.creationdate,'yyyy-MM-dd')
    , ' '
    , q.title) ans_title from posts
         inner join posts q on q.id = posts.parentid 
)

select ownerUserid as [User Link]
, concat(
    'site://a/'
  , [1]
  , '|'
  , (select ans_title
     from answers
     where id = [1])
  ) [ans1]
, concat(
    'site://a/'
  , [2]
  , '|'
  , (select ans_title
     from answers
     where id = [2])
  ) [ans2]
, concat(
    'site://a/'
  , [3]
  , '|'
  , (select ans_title
     from answers
     where id = [3])
  ) [ans3]
, concat(
    'site://a/'
  , [4]
  , '|'
  , (select ans_title
     from answers
     where id = [4])
  ) [ans4]
, concat(
    'site://a/'
  , [5]
  , '|'
  , (select ans_title
     from answers
     where id = [5])
  ) [ans5]
from
(
select OwnerUserid 
      , [1] 
      , [2] 
      , [3] 
      , [4] 
      , [5] 
from ( select *
     from ranked_posts
     WHERE Rank <= 5
) dta
pivot
(
  min(id) 
  for rank in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])
) pvt_data
) all_data
```

When run this is what the result will look like:

[image: result of query with userlink and 5 columns with dates and answer titles]

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the magnificent [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).

Comment: Trust me, the heavy work here is understanding how `PIVOT` works. I didn't back in 2018 ...

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you're missing a `GROUP BY` in your query, even without the `[Answer x]` columns it won't execute.

Second, it's hard to get the top 5 results (per user) in 5 different columns. I hope you're satisfied to get them as rows; then, [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/822859/latests-answers-by-top-users?UserCount=5&MinReputation=100000&MinPostsCount=50) will do the trick.

[image]

Comment: "I hope you're satisfied to get them as rows;" Well, that's actually sad :( But if you say it's tough to get in columns, I assume it definitely must be tough. I'll have to adjust accordingly. Thanks though!